# ContentObserver should call if and only if ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI changes

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contentobserver

As my application uses content from `android.provider.ContactsContract.Data` (API > 11) and `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` (API < 11) to populate `Contacts`.

I've tried to `registerContentObserver()` against these provider. But it calls my `ContentObserver` even if I tries to Call a person from device as soon as  I put the call. It does trigger my `ContentObserver` which is not useful for me as there's no Content Change in `Contacts Provider`.

***Root Cause:***

Seems like `LAST_TIME_CONTACTED` or something in `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` do changes when a call has been made from device which legitimate wokes up by `ContentObserver`.

***Tried:***

```
private class ContactsContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
    public ContactsContentObserver() {
        super(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        Zname.getPreferences().setRefreshContact(true);
    }
}
```

Registered `ContentObserver` in `OnCreate()` of `Activity`

```
ContactsContentObserver contactsContentObserver = new ContactsContentObserver();
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, false, contactsContentObserver);
```

Tried with `notifyForDescendents` as `false` on `registerContentObserver`. Still it triggers out `ContentObserver`

***Ques:***

*How can one register `ContentObserver` which triggers **if and only if contacts information is under CRUD(Create,Update,Delete) except `Last_Time_Contacted` or its descendants?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `android.provider.ContactsContract` content provider has it's own complexity which makes `ContentObserver` tough to notify only on `contacts` content change except it's `LAST_TIME_CONTACTED` field as every fellow come across say these and so it is.

One need to develop it's own logic whether `contacts` data get updated or not when `ContentObserver` notifies.

Points to consider building logic whether `contacts` really get updated or not.

- Checking on these basis of Last Time checked. Depends on the requirement.
- Adding `ContentObserver` in `Service` which is `STICKY` so it can be there when contacts get change.

*Sync Phone Book Logic :-* ***As I've maintained contacts using SQLite, so checking up whether that exist or not and w.r.t building logic.***

```
ContentValues values;
Cursor cursor = Zname.getApplication().getContentResolver().query(DBConstant.All_Contacts_Columns.CONTENT_URI,null,DBConstant.All_Contacts_Columns.COLUMN_CONTACT_NUMBER+ "=?",new String[] { _contact.getContactNumber() },null);

 if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Zname.getApplication().getContentResolver().delete(DBConstant.All_Contacts_Columns.CONTENT_URI,DBConstant.All_Contacts_Columns.COLUMN_CONTACT_NUMBER+ "?=",new String[] { _contact.getContactNumber() });
        Log.i(TAG, "Updating zname phonebook");
        values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBConstant.All_Contacts_Columns.COLUMN_CONTACT_ID,_contact.getContactId());
        values.put(DBConstant.All_Contacts_Columns.COLUMN_CONTACT_NUMBER,_contact.getContactNumber());
        values.put(DBConstant.All_Contacts_Columns.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME,_contact.getContactName());
        values.put(DBConstant.All_Contacts_Columns.COLUMN_ZNAME_DP_URL_SMALL,_contact.getContactPhotoUri().toString());

        Zname.getApplication().getContentResolver().insert(DBConstant.All_Contacts_Columns.CONTENT_URI,values);

        if (cursor != null)
              cursor.close();
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

The fundamental problem here is that registering for `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` isn't working as you might reasonably think.

The reason why you get updates even if `notifyForDescendents` is `false` is because the `Uri` triggering the update is... `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` and *not* the contact row that is being dialled.

The offending code in the Contacts app can be found at [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/android/providers/contacts/ContactsProvider2.java#ContactsProvider2.notifyChange%28boolean%29) and there is a bug filed for this on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39698).

So to answer your question, **you can't register a `ContentObserver` which will trigger for specific fields on a contact.** You would need to have something in your app which will keep track of calculating the differences whenever `onChange` fires.

Comment: Someone wrote there that "From Android 4.3 we have time stamp for each contacts that will be updated whenever we make any change in the particular contacts" . Any idea what he's talking about, and more importantly, how to use it to filter out callbacks that don't help as nothing has changed? Maybe he's talking about this: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns#contact_last_updated_timestamp ?

Comment: Looking on somewhere else, it's also not reliable at all: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57489435/878126