# Any listener or event in android that give me update if contact add or edit in android os book?

Tags: android

I am building one android app and now am stop at one place,

I am not sure if me add new contact or edit contact in android OS book it give me any type of listener or event so according this may do further procedure.

Please, someone know about this please answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create Broadcast Receiver for achieve contact related functionality.

1. [ContactsContract](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html)
2. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733775/broadcast-on-contact-add-change)

This will helps you.

Comment: If app is offline, even not in background and after some time i will open app than any way to get any listener?

Answer (score 2):

You should implement `ContentObserver` in order to manage contact related changes.

For more info check out the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783356/contentobserver-should-call-if-and-only-if-contactscontract-contacts-content-uri).

Comment: If app is offline, even not in background and after some time i will open app than any way to get any listener?